# LibreOffice Calc: conditional formatting with gradient only non-zero values

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice

I have a set of cells which I would like to format conditionally. If they have a non-zero value, I want them to be formatted with a 3-color gradient (green for min, yellow for 0, red for max); if they have a zero value, I want them to stay normal, with white background. How to do that?

What I've tried: Select cells > Format > Conditional formatting > Condition. Cell value is equal to 0, apply style "MyStyle" (which is defined to be explicitly black for text color and white for cell background). Click on "Add", then set All cells, Gradient (3 colors) and set green for min, yellow for 0, red for max. Make sure the Gradient condition is below the "Value is zero".

What happens: All cells that contain a zero value become yellow.

I have tried to set 0.01 as value for the yellow color, but nothing changes. Also, these cells have a format which makes them be displayed as "" if they are 0; I hope this is not messing with the conditional formatting... Anyway I've tried Cell value is equal to "" as a condition, but that doesn't work either.